# Unity how to get component reference on instantiated object

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, game-development, gameobject

```
var playedCard = Instantiate(Cards[selectedCard], spawnLoc[gameQueue - 1], Quaternion.identity);
```

How can i get reference to playedCard's SpriteRenderer?

Comment: By reading the documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering Cards[selectedCard] holds a reference to a GameObject, you can go with

```
var sp = playedCard.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
```

Or if Cards is an array of SpriteRenderer itself, Instantiate should return a new GameObject via its spriteRenderer Reference (you may need to add an explicit cast before Instantiate in this case, as such

```
var sp = (SpriteRenderer)Instantiate(Cards[selectedCard], spawnLoc[gameQueue - 1], Quaternion.identity);
```